# Multiclass classification training data & validation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, conv-neural-network, validation

I am building a CNN based model for multiclass classification.
There are close to 200 data points in my training data and there are a total of 30 classes for these 200 data points.

I am a bit stuck thinking how to carve out the validation data set out of the 200 data points I have. Can I randomly pick up 70% for training and 30% for validation?

Secondly, for some of the classes, the number of samples are very few (some of them can have only 2-3 sample data point). Now, if I randomly pick up, I number of such samples for training data can be very low or even 0.

Can someone provide directions please?

Comment: At first glance, that does not look like a big dataset for a neural net. How many variables are there per data point? How many neurons do you plan to have in that net and how many pathes between those neurons? Leave-one-out-cross-validation comes to mind, but even then, 200 might be too few.

Comment: I don't know how to count number of variables because the training data is consists of English like sentences followed by the class for that sentence. These sentences are processed using NLTK and then represented using a sparse array per data point. Yeah, I agree that the number of data points are very low. I am in the process of collecting additional data points but it might hover around 1000 data points at the max. Currently, I do get good results based on ad hoc testing I have done on the neural network.

Comment: > Currently, I do get good results based on ad hoc testing I have done on the neural network. -- that is a strong point against my worries. Is cross validation an answer to your question, then? LOOC, maybe? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)

Comment: Thanks. I will look up the Wikipedia link you have given. But generally, I would like to follow something that is well accepted in the industry to check that the trained model is performing decently. I could use other methods if not cross validation. any pointers on this will help me a lot.

Comment: I don't know what is accepted in different industries. Maybe I should not have pointed you to Wikipedia but to chapter 7.10 in the 2nd edition of Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman: Elements of statistical learning, Springer Series in Statistics?